# Mybatis After batch Mode update, BatchResult UpdateCounts has -2 values

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

- ENV

  mybatis:3.5.13

oracle11

```
java 1.8
```

- CODE

try(SqlSession session = sessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH, false)){

```
        // update
        for(Map<String, Object> data : selectList){
            session.update(mapperId+"."+updateId, data);
        }

        // check result
        List<BatchResult> batchResultList = session.flushStatements();

        // extract count sum
        int updateCnt  = Arrays.stream(batchResultList.get(0).getUpdateCounts()).sum();

        // diff
        if(updateCnt != selectList.size()){

              session.rollback();
              return 0;
        }

        // DB commit
        session.commit();
```

}

- VALUES

  selectList size = 3
  updateCnt = -6
- happens

actually even 3 rows effected, updateCnt has -6 value

and it worked normally in mysql

jdbc url connection properties change
(defaultBatchValue)

Answer (score 0):

is it related ?

The oracle-documentation states:

• For a prepared statement batch, it is not possible to know the number of rows affected in the database by each individual statement in the batch. Therefore, all array elements have a value of -2. According to the JDBC 2.0 specification, a value of -2 indicates that the operation was successful but the number of rows affected is unknown.

• For a generic statement batch, the array contains the actual update counts indicating the number of rows affected by each operation. The actual update counts can be provided only in the case of generic statements in the Oracle implementation of standard batching.

• For a callable statement batch, the server always returns the value 1 as the update count, irrespective of the number rows affected by each operation.

Comment: And , is it called final long[] executeBatchFromQueue()  method in OraclePreparedStatement class?
so -2 value is predicted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).